# How can I get my components to detect their own height and width in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript2.0

I decided to dive into using CSS Grids with Angular and one of the things I'm working on is a function that will allow the components to dynamically generate their own grids proportionate to the golden ratio based on their own measurements.  I've used `@ViewChild` in conjunction with adding a `#someName` to the element I want to call so I figured that same principal would apply to targeting a parent container or its' own self.  I've come across `ElementRef` and `TemplateRef` but those seem to only target children of the component.

In a lot instances I could very well achieve this by using the `@ViewChild` in the parent component and sending the size into the child component through an `@Input`.  The only thing I'd crash on with that idea is instances where a component is loading in a `<router-outlet>`.  Is there a method I can use for doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Original Answer

In fact, if you want a component or directive to be aware of the specifics of its host or a parent element, you need an `ElementRef`, and the way to pass that reference to the component is via Dependency Injection.

Consider a component called `SomeParentComponent` and this other component, which is child of it:

```
@Component({ 
selector: 'some-child'
.. 
})
export class SomeChildComponent {
  constructor( @Self() private element: ElementRef ) {}
}
```

By using the `@Self` decorator and injecting an `ElementRef` in the constructor, you get a reference to the `<some-child>` element, and so you can query for specific properties of the `element.nativeElement` like `offsetHeight` and `offsetWidth`.

Beware, however, when you query for those properties, since if you have projected content using `<ng-content>` inside the template of `some-child`, or you're instantiating another component, you will get different values for those properties in different lifecycle hooks, since for instance, projected content only exists from `ngAfterContentInit` onwards.

You can also get a reference of the parent component, or any component up in the component tree, by injecting it in the constructor:

```
@Component({ 
selector: 'some-child'
.. 
})
export class SomeChildComponent {
  constructor( @Host() private someParent: SomeParentComponent ) {}
}
```

This way you can access the class definition of `SomeParentComponent`, use  and even modify its public properties.

Even though both `@Host` and `@Self` decorators use is kinda optional, it makes clearer what you're passing as a dependency to your component.

---

### Edit 11/17/2017

In order to access the properties of your injected `ElementRef` there's a couple of alternatives, you could use value accessors or just a plain class method:

```
@Component({...})
export class SomeChildComponent implements OnInit {
  // Using a getter accesor for each property
  get height(): number {
    return this.element.offsetHeight;
  }
  get width(): number {
    return this.element.offsetWidth;
  }

  // Using a getter accesor for both properties
  get dimensions(): { width: number, height: number } {
    return { width: this.element.offsetWidth, height: this.element.offsetHeight  }
  }

  constructor( @Self() private element: ElementRef ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log( this.height ); // this.element.nativeElement.offsetHeight
    console.log( this.width ); // this.element.nativeElement.offsetWidth
    console.log( this.dimensions ); // { width: this.element.offsetWidth, height: this.element.offsetHeight  }
    console.log( this.getDimensions() ); // { width: this.element.offsetWidth, height: this.element.offsetHeight  }
  }

  // Using a class method
  getDimensions() {
    return { width: this.element.offsetWidth, height: this.element.offsetHeight  }
  }
}
```

Comment: as far as how the params will vary depending on the lifecycle, if I had `someChildComponent` defined in a `grid-area` in the `someParentComponent`  and called a function in the `ngOnInit()` of the `someChildComponent` that detected it's own width, would that param be accurate?  I'd rather not wait until after the component loads the content before scaling the grid.  The height doesn't really matter because I'm calculating the cell heights based on the width inside the function.

Comment: I think it should be alright, unless inside the template of `someChildComponent` you have other components or projected content, as I mentioned before. I don't think there's an answer that will suit all of the possible cases, cause the output might vary depending on the content of each component. If you provide a plunker I could give you a hand.

Comment: ok I'm stuck on something with using this solution.  After I instantiate `@Self() element: ElementRef` in the constructor, how do I target the height, width etc. through a function?

Comment: I'm going to edit my comment with the answer right now